# Can a column in a composite unique index auto-increment only to avoid duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Say you have a table with a composite `UNIQUE` index – for example, a table of `event_contributors` holding people (users) who have contributed to an event in different capacities (roles), and who should be listed by role in a specific order. Something like this (simplified to scalar values for illustrative purposes – would of course be a pivot table in real life):

| event | user | role | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Garden Party | John | Organiser | 3 |
| Garden Party | Jill | Caterer | 1 |
| Garden Party | Mike | Organiser | 1 |
| Garden Party | Andy | DJ | 1 |
| Garden Party | Ross | Organiser | 2 |
| Workshop | Andy | Organiser | 1 |
| Workshop | Jill | Organiser | 2 |

And when nicely listed:

> Catering: Jill
> DJ: Andy
> Organisers: Mike, Ross and John [← note sequence]

This requires that the combination of event + role + sequence be unique, so you make a `UNIQUE` index on those three columns.

To avoid duplicates, you can make `sequence` an auto-incrementing column, but that will make it increment on *every* new row, so it more or less just becomes synonymous with the primary key (or *becomes* the primary key). If the presentation order is always fixed, that’s not much of an issue, but if the system needs to allow for reordering (e.g., change “Mike, Ross and John” to “John, Mike and Ross” in the example above), a globally unique sequence column makes things far more complicated.

You can also solve it outside the database, by fetching `MAX(sequence) + 1` with the appropriate constraints and passing the returned value explicitly when inserting the new record; but (a) you risk a race condition where someone else inserts a sequence between your fetching the next available sequence number and inserting a record with it; and (b) it’s an extra DB query for every insert.

So I got to wondering if there is a way to define the table/column/index that will make the database essentially do the same thing directly: if there’s already a record with the given event + role + sequence combination, then auto-increment `sequence` enough that the insertion can succeed; but only auto-increment if necessary to avoid a duplicate, not with every insertion.

Is this something that is possible to do in SQL?

Comment: Why don't you want it to just increment on every new row and be globally unique in the table? If you are just going to generate a new sequence number every time you encounter a duplicate `event, role` they aren't adding anything to the uniqueness requirement. The unique constraint isn't enforcing anything other than being a unique row identifier either way.

Comment: @MartinSmith Mainly for reordering purposes. In the example in the question, if I later want to reorder Mike, Ross and John by putting John first, that’s easy to do if the sequence only needs to be sequential and unique within that event/role combination (update sequence to be 1 where user is John, increment by 1 where sequence >= 1 and user isn’t John); if it’s globally unique, it’s a lot more complicated to switch around, because you can’t update an identity column – and even if you could, you’d have to avoid collision with sequence numbers from other events/roles.

Comment: You don't need to make it an IDENTITY column - you can still use a SEQUENCE and then the column is updatable. And you can still enforce uniqueness on the combination of three columns rather than just on the sequence column to allow re-ordering within an `event, role` without having to update other rows from different `event, role` if you would get a clash on the sequence

Comment: @MartinSmith Despite the column name used in the example here, I had never heard of `SEQUENCE` – that could indeed work! If you write that up as an answer, I’ll happily upvote it. Seems the only remaining issue would be one of neatness: `1, 2, 3` just _looks_ neater than `2937, 6352, 11927`.

Comment: You can easily get "nice" sequential display orderings with `row_number` in order of the sequence so this doesn't need to be displayed to end users (though you would ideally need to keep track of it behind the scenes for UI that allows Updates/Deletes)

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, I wasn’t thinking about end users – just neatness when looking in the actual database itself (admittedly more of a my-OCD issue rather than an _actual_ issue).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  TBH it depends on the size and purpose of the database. If this is some low volume hobby project I might prefer to sacrifice concurrency for "nicer" values. Other than that I'd suggest just using `ROW_NUMBER` to get these sequential values as and when you want to imagine that method had been used

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server the hidden `UNIQUEIFIER` column for a non unique clustered index key works somewhat similarly to how you suggest but this is a behind the scenes matter and not usable for this purpose.

As a frame challenge I would approach the matter something like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EventContributorSequence 
    AS INT
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1  ;  


CREATE TABLE event_contributors 
    (event_contributor_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, /*Stable primary key not subject to updates*/
     [event] varchar(12) NOT NULL, 
     [user] varchar(4) NOT NULL, 
     [role] varchar(9) NOT NULL , 
     [sequence] int DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR EventContributorSequence,
     UNIQUE([event], [role], [sequence])
);
    
INSERT INTO event_contributors
    ([event], [user], [role])
VALUES
    ('Garden Party', 'John', 'Organiser'),
    ('Garden Party', 'Jill', 'Caterer'),
    ('Garden Party', 'Mike', 'Organiser'),
    ('Garden Party', 'Andy', 'DJ'),
    ('Garden Party', 'Ross', 'Organiser'),
    ('Workshop', 'Andy', 'Organiser'),
    ('Workshop', 'Jill', 'Organiser')
;
```

The `sequence` is incremented for all rows - not just within a partition. But if you prefer looking at "nicer" values you can use ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oxv9jAZa))

```
SELECT [event],
       [role],
       [sequence],
       ROW_NUMBER()
         OVER (
           PARTITION BY [event], [role]
           ORDER BY [sequence]) AS CalcSequence
FROM   event_contributors
ORDER  BY [event],
          [role],
          [sequence]
```

The reason I opted for a composite unique constraint on `[event], [role], [sequence]` rather than just on `[sequence]` is because the comments indicate that there is a desire to potentially update the `[sequence]` column to re order rows within a `[event], [role]` partition and this avoids having to worry about the sequence clashing with something in a different one.

The `event_contributor_id` column is to provide something stable so the PK doesn't change when you reorder rows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, each `role` should have a unique ID in the `roles` table. And every `event` should have a unique ID in the `events` table. (These can be auto-incremental, such as by way of marking them as identities.)

Then your `event_contributors` linking table should just store the combination of those unique IDs and have a unique index on `(eventId, roleId, sequence)`. They won't be auto-incremental in the `event_contributors` table, so they'll be distinct from the primary key, whatever you end up choosing it to be. But to be honest, I'd just make *that* the primary key of the `event_contributors` table itself anyway, and the unique constraint will come with that automatically.

Comment: I don’t really see how this answers the question… Obviously `event`, `user` and `role` should be foreign keys; I only showed them as scalar values for simplicity, to illustrate the purpose of the table, but that has no relation to what I’m asking at all. The unique index on those three columns is exactly what I already describe in the question, but setting a unique index will not auto-increment the sequence column.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet TBH, not really clear what your question actually is?...are you saying you want the `sequence` to auto-increment but only within the scope of the `event`, and then reset on each `event`?

Comment: No, not just each event. The scope is the combination of `event + role`, so it should reset on each new `event + role` constellation. So people who perform the same role at the same event (e.g., organisers for the garden party) will have an internal sequencing, as in the example table in the question. If I add another organiser to the garden party, their sequence number would be 4, but if I add a cleaner to the garden party, theirs would be 1 (because there aren’t any existing rows that combine garden party + cleaner).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Gotcha. Martin's answer is probably helpful for what you're looking for. The only issue (going back to neatness of the numbers) is by using an auto-incrementing feature like a sequence object, you'll end up with contiguous numbers, which look nice, but make updating the order a little bit of a pain. Typically a `sequence` / `sort` field stores numbers with gaps so when you need to add a new row, rarely should you have to update **every** other row. Better from a database efficiency standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> you can make sequence an auto-incrementing column

That feature does not exist.

Seems like you need `UNIQUE(user,role)`.  And use client code or a `TRIGGER` or a stored function to set `sequence`.

**OR...**

If `sequence` is just for ordering and does not need to have "consecutive" numbers:

```
sequence INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

PRIMARY KEY(user, role),
INDEX(sequence)   -- sufficient for auto_inc
```

That will provide an ordering that is based on when the row was added to the table.  The values of `sequence` would probably be distinct and usually not consecutive.

With this, there is no need for client code, Triggers, etc.

Comment: I was thinking about defining `sequence` with auto-increment and using the composite index as the primary key without auto-incrementing when I wrote that particular bit. `UNIQUE(user, role)` will not work, since users can have the same role on multiple events. The primary concern is that contributors within each role for each event must be _sequentially ordered_, so the composite index must be on `event, role, sequence`. An additional unique index on `event, user, role` would be a good idea too (to avoid one person being organiser of the same event twice).

Comment: Using client code to set the sequence is what I’ve always done, and what I’m trying to improve on; using a trigger might be worth looking into, I hadn’t thought about that at all!

Comment: The ordering -- Does it need to be just ordering and not consecutive numbers?  Check out my addition.

Comment: Ideally I would like consecutive numbers always starting at 1 – but that's just me being OCD for when I need to look at the actual table once in a while. The actual _need_ is just for ordering.